# Primefaces Push - nothing happes

Tags: primefaces, atmosphere, primefaces-push

I try to get primeface push counter example going. I *think* I have the libraries right because on server start-up it shows me

```html
nstalled AtmosphereHandler org.primefaces.push.impl.PushEndpointHandlerProxy mapped to context-path /test1234 and Broadcaster Class org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster
1732 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Installed AtmosphereInterceptor [@PushEndpoint Interceptor] mapped to AtmosphereHandler org.primefaces.push.impl.PushEndpointHandlerProxy
```

and there are no errors at all.there are also no other outputs.

Thank you all for help,
Duesentrieb

here the files:

web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 version="3.0">

 <display-name>pages</display-name>

 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
  <param-value>server</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <!-- context-param> <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name> 
  <param-value>false</param-value> </context-param -->

 <!-- context-param> <param-name>primefaces.PUSH_SERVER_URL</param-name> 
  <param-value>http://127.0.0.1:8080</param-value> </context-param -->
  
  
<!-- PrimeFaces Configuration -->
<!--    <context-param> -->
<!--       <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name> -->
<!--       <param-value>Bootstrap</param-value> -->
<!--    </context-param>   -->


 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>product/product.xhtml</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>


 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
  <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterCacheClass</param-name>
  <param-value>org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache</param-value>
  </init-param>
<!--   <init-param> -->
<!--    <param-name>org.atmosphere.useNative</param-name> -->
<!--    <param-value>true</param-value> -->
<!--   </init-param> -->
<!--   <init-param> -->
<!--    <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.sessionSupport</param-name> -->
<!--    <param-value>true</param-value> -->
<!--   </init-param> -->
<!--   <init-param> -->
<!--    <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterClass</param-name> -->
<!--    <param-value>org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster</param-value> -->
<!--   </init-param> -->
<!--   <init-param> -->
<!--    <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.CometSupport.maxInactiveActivity</param-name> -->
<!--    <param-value>1800000</param-value> -->
<!--   </init-param> -->
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  <async-supported>true</async-supported>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <error-page>
  <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
  <location>/public/product/product.xhtml</location>
 </error-page>
 <filter>
  <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.knightcnc.web.filter.AuthFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>




</web-app>
```

counter.xhtml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
 xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">

<head>


</head>
<h:body>
 <h:form id="form">
  <h:outputText id="out" value="#{globalCounterView.count}"
   styleClass="ui-widget display" />

  <p:commandButton value="Click"
   actionListener="#{globalCounterView.increment}" />
 </h:form>
   

 <p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/test1234" />


<script type="text/javascript">
function handleMessage(data) {
 alert("Hola");
 $('.display').html(data);
}
</script>

</h:body>
</html>
```

GlobalCounterView.java

```html
package test.primefaces.showcase.push.counter;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

import org.primefaces.push.EventBus;
import org.primefaces.push.EventBusFactory;
 
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class GlobalCounterView implements Serializable{
 
    /**
  * 
  */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1234L;
 private volatile int count;
    
 
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
 
    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
     
    public void increment() {
        count++;
         
        EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus(); 
        eventBus.publish("/test1234", String.valueOf(count));
    }
}
```

CounterRessource.java

```html
package test.primefaces.showcase.push.counter;

import org.primefaces.push.EventBus;
import org.primefaces.push.RemoteEndpoint;
import org.primefaces.push.annotation.OnClose;
import org.primefaces.push.annotation.OnMessage;
import org.primefaces.push.annotation.OnOpen;
import org.primefaces.push.annotation.PushEndpoint;
import org.primefaces.push.impl.JSONEncoder;
 
@PushEndpoint("/test1234")
public class CounterResource {
 
    @OnMessage(encoders = {JSONEncoder.class})
    public String onMessage(String count) {
     System.out.println("CounterResource.onMessage()");
        return count;
    }
    
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen( RemoteEndpoint r, EventBus e ) {
     System.out.println("Eventbus On Open");
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose( RemoteEndpoint r, EventBus e ) {
     System.out.println("Eventbus On Close");
    }
    
}
```

end of (because characters limitation here) console output *after* the first call of the page counter.xhtml

```html
...

AFTER_DEFAULT 
1871 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Browser disconnection detection with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
1871 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Installed AtmosphereInterceptor org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor with priority BEFORE_DEFAULT 
1871 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Using EndpointMapper class org.primefaces.push.impl.PushEndpointMapper
1871 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Using BroadcasterCache: org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache
1871 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Default Broadcaster Class: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster
1871 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Broadcaster Shared List Resources: false
1871 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Broadcaster Polling Wait Time 100
1871 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Shared ExecutorService supported: true
1871 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Messaging ExecutorService Pool Size unavailable - Not instance of ThreadPoolExecutor
1872 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Async I/O Thread Pool Size: 200
1872 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Using BroadcasterFactory: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcasterFactory
1872 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Using AtmosphereResurceFactory: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAtmosphereResourceFactory
1872 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Using WebSocketProcessor: org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor
1876 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Invoke AtmosphereInterceptor on WebSocket message true
1876 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - HttpSession supported: false
1876 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Atmosphere is using DefaultAtmosphereObjectFactory for dependency injection and object creation
1876 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Atmosphere is using async support: org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport running under container: Apache Tomcat/8.0.30 using javax.servlet/3.0 and jsr356/WebSocket API
1877 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Atmosphere Framework 2.3.5 started.
1877 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - 

 For Atmosphere Framework Commercial Support, visit 
 http://www.async-io.org/ or send an email to support@async-io.org

1884 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Installed AtmosphereInterceptor @PushEndpoint Interceptor with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
Dec 17, 2015 3:17:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Dec 17, 2015 3:17:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Dec 17, 2015 3:17:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4564 ms
2007 [Thread-3] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Latest version of Atmosphere's JavaScript Client 2.2.12
2007 [Thread-3] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - 

 Atmosphere Framework Updates
 Minor available (bugs fixes): 2.3.6
 Major available (new features): 2.4.1.4
Dec 17, 2015 3:17:37 PM org.apache.myfaces.util.ExternalSpecifications isUnifiedELAvailable
INFO: MyFaces Unified EL support enabled
Dec 17, 2015 3:17:37 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.Tomcat7AnnotationLifecycleProvider newInstance
INFO: Creating instance of test.primefaces.showcase.push.counter.GlobalCounterView
```

Comment: So, I'm trying now to exchange the atmosphere versions and when I use 2.4.rc6 I get following Error:


`java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.atmosphere.config.service.EndpoinMapperService not present`


Took me a while to find out why, because the class is in the jar. But without the typo: EndpoinMapperService is missing the t after Endpoin.

Comment: version 2.3.0-rc6 - sorry.

Comment: you should update details in question instead of comment, Also try to include only as much code as is necessary to illustrate the problem instead of dumping your entire project... this will help you to get more useful answers.